# How to use Index position as filename

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a text file for each string in a series of pandas dataframe.

I'd like to name the file with Index number of the series so that, at a glance, I can be confident that I've got the corresponding file for the index.

I've not been able to find a solution on SO and don't really have an idea on how to pass the index number into the file name

A sample of the data is download-able [here](https://files.fm/u/cmdetrzm).

Below is the code I'm using to number the file

```
d = testdata
file = 'data/app_name/{}app_name.txt'

n = 0 # to number the files
for row in d.iteritems():
    with open(file.format(n), 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(row))
        n += 1
```

Partial Solution is:

```
testdata.sort_index(inplace=True)

d = testdata
file = 'data/description/{}app_name.txt'

n = 1 # to number the files
for row in d.iteritems():
    with open(file.format(n), 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(row))
        n += 1
```

However, I'd prefer to find a solution that where I wouldn't need to sort every dataset I work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = testdata
file = 'data/app_name/{}app_name.txt'

n = 0 # to number the files
for row in d.iteritems():
    with open(file.format(row[0]), 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(row))
        n += 1
```

Wouldn't you just grab the first column then?  So row[0] would be your numerical value?

Comment: I changed 'n' to 'row[0] and that did do the trick! Thanks, I knew it'd be something simple just couldn't figure out what.
Just as a reference if I always  use 'row[0]' will it always use the index?

Comment: row[0] would be the first  column.  Think of it like a list, the first item would be 0, the second would be 1.  That is essentially what it is.  The loop iterates over each row, pulling the list of items.

Comment: So if the numerical index I'm using wasn't sorted it would come out in random order but still maintain the index number?

Comment: yes.  Because index 0 of row is just the first position in the list, and the first position in the list is the index number from the data.

Comment: Understood! Appreciate the help and I now understand this a little better.